# How to generate a view with checkboxes from an array

Tags: php, html, forms, cakephp-2.3

We have an array `$options` with a flexible number of values. This Values we get from an DB.
How can we generate the view that this View look like

`options['value-1']` checkbox_1

`options['value_n']` checkbox_n

Is there a way to generate this view-element via an forloop something like

```
for (i=1 to n) {
   echo $this->Form->input('database-field', array('type'=>'checkbox','div' => true));
}
```

how do i this in cakephp 2.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for printing more than one checkbox from an array of values? I hope this will help you:

```
echo $this->Form->input('database-field' ,array('options'=> $options, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

Update:

```
echo $this->Form->input('database-field' ,array('options'=> $options, 'multiple' => 'checkbox','style' => 'float: left; display: inline'));
```

or

```
echo $this->Form->input('database-field' ,array('options'=> $options, 'multiple' => 'checkbox','div' => 'false'));
```

Comment: Thats works fine, but how can i change it that i don't see every entry on a single line